# Animate image sequence with javascript on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, sequence

Hi all I have a set of images that need to be animated on scroll event as if they were movie frames.

here's my markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            ....

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <img src="images/phone20.png" />
            <img src="images/phone19.png" />
            <img src="images/phone18.png" />
            <img src="images/phone17.png" />
            <img src="images/phone16.png" />
            <img src="images/phone15.png" />
            <img src="images/phone14.png" />
            <img src="images/phone13.png" />
            <img src="images/phone12.png" />
            <img src="images/phone11.png" />
            <img src="images/phone10.png" />
            <img src="images/phone9.png" />
            <img src="images/phone8.png" />
            <img src="images/phone7.png" />
            <img src="images/phone6.png" />
            <img src="images/phone5.png" />
            <img src="images/phone4.png" />
            <img src="images/phone3.png" />
            <img src="images/phone2.png" />
            <img src="images/phone1.png" />

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Basically I'd like to show/hide them one by one on scroll event either with opacity or with display attribute. What would be the best approach? Finding the delta value or the scrolltop value? All ideas welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you wanting the screen to actually move or just show the slides on top of each other - if the latter (without screen movement you may want to use a [ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) making use of the [slide event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) to get a value you can use to animate your images

Comment: Doens't matter if the screen moves as long as the sequence is triggered by the mouse wheel

Comment: check this tutorial... http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/  I think it does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.
Edit the `scrollResolution`to control the speed.

```
var picture = $('#main img');
var pictureCount = picture.length;
var scrollResolution = 75;    

function animateScroll() {
    var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);

    if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
        imageIndex = pictureCount - 1;
    }

    picture.hide();
    picture.eq(imageIndex).show();
}

animateScroll();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    animateScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
function animateScroll(container) {

  var img = $(container).find('.sequence img');

   $(container).find('.sequence img').eq(0).hide()
       .next('img').show()
       .end().appendTo($(container).find('.sequence'));
}      

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    animateScroll('#main');
}
```